# Problems with HEAD revision

Tags: git, macos, osx-elcapitan

I try to execute command `git rev-list HEAD --count` on Mac OS X 10.11 in script.

```
#!/bin/bash
git=`sh /etc/profile; which git`
buildNumber=`"$git" rev-list --all |wc -l`
echo "$buildNumber"
```

But I get next errors:

> usage: git rev-list [OPTION] ... [ -- paths... ]   limiting
>   output:
>       --max-count=

My script locates in `gitRepository/Folder/Scripts/my_script.sh`

If I run `git rev-list HEAD --count` in root git folder I get the result 1049, but if I run it from `../Scripts` I get an error:

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the
>   working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
>   'git <command> [...] -- [...]'

It's not an empty repository.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is this a new repository with no commits in it yet?  Normally, if git can't open the `HEAD` file, it just complains that you don't even have a repository; here, it's acting like the `HEAD` reference is a symbolic reference to a branch that does not exist, which is the normal state of a new repository.

Comment: If, for some reasons, you've lost .git/HEAD file, you may re-create it with a text editor. The format is `<SHA1>` or `ref: refs/heads/<BRANCH_NAME>`

Comment: are you in "detached head" mode? Try a "git status" and see if you are. If so, try: "git checkout master" and re-run your command

Answer (score 0):

In most situations, Git commands that need to read/write to a specific repository, i.e., most commands aside from things like configuration and help need to be executed somewhere from within a git repository. This would mean any directory that contains a `.git` directory plus its sub-directories and also the root directory of a bare repository.

The error you are getting indicates that the current directory is not a Git directory.

To fix this either `cd` to the desired directory or use something like the following command:

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/repo/.git rev-list HEAD --count
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct command, in addition of adding --git-dir with the proper Git repo folder, would be:

```
git rev-list --count HEAD
```

See [commit 8d6ba49](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d6ba49563600d8e65c7f56fb0f29e23a571a75f), [commit b00b6ac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b00b6ace5c92ef4c2893f7b7cc597a0297812a52), [commit 61de0ff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/61de0ff695cf632f1a17fc0ebd4401bde2f7fa8f), [commit dcbaa0b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dcbaa0b361f5bebcbe6eca446819fadd02083461), [commit bdbc17e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bdbc17e86abe2471c4bd0d52cdc004835cb7bb3e), [commit a378fee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a378fee5b0795d671722d803b93b7b32941c0067), [commit 441ee35](https://github.com/git/git/commit/441ee35d8384fe7f6328584ac1634da14ed42e11) (05 Oct 2018) by [Matthew DeVore (`matvore`)](https://github.com/matvore).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f2e2136](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f2e2136ad7291524a2b67a179dea493f4a562453), 16 Oct 2018)</sup>

> ### `tests`: order arguments to git-rev-list properly
>
> It is a common mistake to put positional arguments before flags when invoking `git-rev-list`.
> **Order the positional arguments last**.

For example, do NOT do:

```
git -C pc1 rev-list HEAD --quiet --objects --missing=print
```

But:

```
git -C pc1 rev-list --quiet --objects --missing=print HEAD
```